# Looking for chat source for web application (web socket/ajax)

Tags: php, chat, ajax

I'm looking for chat source to be added to my web application (based on php lang). Here is the list of requirements, looking forward for your help.

- It should be only open source code, I want to be able add changes myself any time I want
- It may be free of charge or paid.
- Web socket / ajax technology
- I think I need a simple chat bot for the beginning
- I want to be able easy implement it with existing auth engine
- Obviously, it should be secure as much as possible
- I don't need video conference support

I already reviewed a lot of options, but they are not looking good as for me, that is why I'm asking for your advice.

Thank Lynob for comment.
When I said open source I meant that I want to get all module code, I want everything to be placed on my server. So, obviously, I want to store chat history in database. For the next - I reviewed a lot of examples, so if you have suggestion that much even 4 of 7 from my requirements - that means that I didn't see it.

Comment: `free or paid`, means not open source - What option have you viewed so that we dont suggest the same things? and do you need db integration or not? should the chat be stored? should it be encrypted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [ppmessage](https://github.com/PPMESSAGE/ppmessage) suite with your requirement.

> With PPMessage, you can chat with visitor or customer via Web or mobile App as open source Intercom alternative.

And also, it has [Web SDK](https://ppmessage.gitbooks.io/ppbook-en/content/part2/ppcom/web-sdk.html). And this is some ocassions :

> Classic occasions: suppose you have a website with its own user system and you integrate PPCom with you website. Your website user can perform operations like sign in, change profile and log out. When user performs these operations, you should invoke Web SDK API to display PPCom correctly.

It has events :

1. User open your website
2. User sign in
3. User modify his profile
4. User sign out from your website

To install it, it's easy :

```
git clone https://github.com/PPMESSAGE/ppmessage.git
cd ppmessage
# mac
bash ppmessage/scripts/set-up-ppmessage-on-mac.sh
# linux
bash ppmessage/scripts/set-up-ppmessage-on-linux.sh
# watch the logs
./ppmessage.py
```

Then go to 127.0.0.1:8945, and follow the instruction. And here is interesting part, it has test function, to make sure everything is work, go to 127.0.0.1:8945/ppconsole/#/app/settings/integrate. You will see in the right bottom an icon to chat, that's for customer. And go to 127.0.0.1:8945/ppkefu/#/app/conversation-list as web administrator to reply the chat.

To sum it up :

> It should be only open source code, I want to be able add changes
>   myself any time I want

You can check the code, it use python, sqlalchemy (mysql, postgresql, sqlite), and redis.

> It may be free of charge or paid.

Check

> Web socket / ajax technology

It use Tornado (www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)

> I think I need a simple chat bot for the beginning

For bot part, after I check the api (https:// ppmessage.gitbooks.io/ppbook-en/content/part2/third-party-app/api/index.html), it has some properties like this :

```
'robot_user_uuid': None,
'robot_train_track': None,
'robot_train_click': None,
'robot_train_method': None,
'robot_train_chat': None,
```

Maybe it can be use.

> I want to be able easy implement it with existing auth engine

It has event (above) you can try that.

> Obviously, it should be secure as much as possible

Well, in my opinion, it is not strong enough, but you have the code, then you can improve it.

> I don't need video conference support

I think it does not support